# Existence of a finite set of sentences $\Delta$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Let $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2$ be sets of sentences s.t. for any structure $M$ it holds that:
>
> $M\vDash \Gamma_1 \iff M\not\vDash \Gamma_2 $
>
> Show that exists a finite set of sentences $\Delta$ s.t. for any sentence $A$, it holds that $\Gamma_1 \vDash A \iff \Delta \vDash A$.

I got lost with all the iff's. I tried assuming towards contradiction but I could only contradict one case. I can't see how the information about $\Gamma_2$ is helpful, and I certainly can't come up with such $\Delta$ that have that property (and any $\Delta$ which is a subset of either $\Gamma_1$,$\Gamma_2$, or $\Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2$ seems not suitable). Would appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the desired $\Delta$ is indeed a subtheory of $\Gamma_1$ - which is reasonable, since being a subtheory of $\Gamma_1$ gives us one of our three "goal conditions" immediately, namely being entailed by $\Gamma_1$ itself.

I've broken my answer into a series of exercises:

---

As you say, the main difficulty with this problem comes from its phrasing, and the "nested implications" it contains. It helps to break things down as we go along. Let's start with the hypothesis in question, namely $$\forall M(M\models\Gamma_1\iff M\models\Gamma_2).$$

This has two pieces which are much easier to think about on their own:

- No structure can satisfy **both** $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ - that is, $\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2$ is unsatisfiable.
- On the other hand, every structure **does** have to satisfy one or the other.

Besides being individually simpler than the whole hypothesis itself, these sub-hypotheses can be considered one at a time, which helps us see how our argument should flow. Specifically, while the latter is a bit subtle, the first is very nice in that it suggests an immediate first step - namely, whenever we have an unsatisfiable theory (in this case $\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2$), we can get a subtheory $\Theta$ which is itself unsatisfiable but is "simpler" in a particular sense:

> The **compactness theorem** then says that there is some finite $\Theta\subseteq\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2$ which is itself unsatisfiable.

OK, so we have a "simple" (in the above sense) theory $\Theta\subseteq\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2$ which is unsatisfiable. This $\Theta$ has a "$\Gamma_1$-part" and a "$\Gamma_2$-part," namely $\Theta\cap \Gamma_1$ and $\Theta\cap \Gamma_2$ respectively. Now right off the bat we see from this decomposition a theory which is pretty close to what we want, and so which we'll choose as our $\Delta$:

> The theory $\Theta\cap\Gamma_1$ is finite, and we have $\Gamma_1\models\Theta\cap\Gamma_1$. So we'll set $\Delta=\Theta\cap\Gamma_1$.

Per the above, we only need to show that this $\Delta$ entails $\Gamma_1$ itself. The second bulletpoint gives an equivalent rephrasing of this, and consequently a different way to phrase our goal:

> Suppose no model of $\Delta$ satisfies $\Gamma_2$. Then every model of $\Delta$ must satisfy $\Gamma_1$, since every structure - and so a fortiori every model of $\Delta$ - satisfies *one of* $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$. So all we need to prove is that $\Delta\cup\Gamma_2$ is unsatisfiable.

But this follows immediately from the definition of $\Delta$:

> We have $\Delta\cup\Gamma_2\supseteq\Theta$.

Comment: Given a model $M$ s.t. $M\vDash \Delta = \Theta \cap \Gamma_1$, how exactly can you follow with $M \not \vDash \Gamma_2$?  $\Delta$ is not an arbitrary subset of $\Gamma_1$ so I don't see how compactness can hold.

Comment: @gbi1977 It's enough to show that $\Delta\cup\Gamma_2$ is unsatisfiable. Can you think of a subset of $\Delta\cup\Gamma_2$ which you already know is unsatisfiable? (HINT: $\Delta\cup\Gamma_2=(\Theta\cap\Gamma_1)\cup\Gamma_2=(\Theta\setminus\Gamma_2)\cup\Gamma_2$.)

Comment: To put it more explicitly, do you mean: $M\vDash \Delta \implies M\not \vDash \Delta \cup \Gamma_2 \implies M\vDash \Delta \cup \Gamma_1 \implies M\vDash \Gamma_1$?

Comment: @gbi1977 I'd phrase it instead as follows. We **never** have $M\models\Delta\cup\Gamma_2$, since $\Delta\cup\Gamma_2$ is outright unsatisfiable (do you see why?). This means that **if** $M\models\Delta$ then we can't have $M\models\Gamma_2$ (if $M\models\Delta$ and $M\models\Gamma_2$ then $M\models\Delta\cup\Gamma_2$), and if $M\not\models\Gamma_2$ then $M\models\Gamma_1$. Putting it all together we get $M\models\Delta\implies M\models\Gamma_1$.